# Is it possible to create an "HOC" which adds markup in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, higher-order-components

In React, I would often construct HOCs which would wrap a component with some bit of markup. For example,

```
const WithLabel = WrappedComponent => ({ label, ...props }) => (
  <label>
    <div>{label}</div>
    <WrappedComponent {...props }/>
  </label>
);
```

Is there an equivalent construct for this sort of thing in Vue? I've read the documentation on mixins and slots and have seen many examples and read articles on how others are creating HOCs in Vue. But none of the examples or libraries I've seen seem to be able to handle markup decoration.